# trying to insert values inside an excel file using PHP

Tags: php, excel

I am trying to insert the values of a variable from a foreach loop into an excel file, so that in the end all my records are dynamically inserted into the excel file. I studied over the net but I couldn't find anything suitable, so any inputs are highly appreciated here.

Comment: what have you tried so far ? any code "not suitable found on the web" that you attempted to modify to suit your needs ? have you searched SO as well ? [many Q/A here](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+values+to+excel)

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stackoverflow! Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: yes . i have studied stack overflow as well. i came across a package called PHPExcel but i coudn'nt figure out , how to use it.

Comment: [PHP Excel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel) . Download it, upload it to your server. (the folder PHPExcel-1.8 or whatever version) and then check [this](https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Examples&referringTitle=Home)

Comment: thanks @AntonisTsimourtos so i checked out the link that you have sent, but can yiu explain what these lines are doing.

Comment: /** Error reporting */
error_reporting(E_ALL);

/** Include path **/
ini_set('include_path', ini_get('include_path').';../Classes/');

/** PHPExcel */
include 'PHPExcel.php';

/** PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007 */
include 'PHPExcel/Writer/Excel2007.php';

Comment: it's from the example on that page.

Comment: so far i have done this...

Comment: <?php 
require_once 'Classes/PHPExcel.php';
require_once 'Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';
require_once 'Classes/PHPExcel/Reader/Excel2007.php';

$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load("try.xlsx");
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$row = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getHighestRow()+1;
//echo $row;
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A'.$row, "hi");
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('B'.$row, "hi");
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('C'.$row, "hi");
$objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007($objPHPExcel);
$objWriter->save('try.xlsx');
?>

Comment: Search other posts too... [here](http://consistentcoder.com/create-an-excel-file-in-php)

Comment: alright . thank you very much, i'll go through this.

Answer (score 0):

I found this looking for the other way around (exel to php).

Class file

```
<?php
/*
    This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
    it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
    the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
    (at your option) any later version.

    This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
    but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
    MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
    GNU General Public License for more details.

    You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
    along with this program.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
*/

/*

    Filename    : export.xls.class.php
    Description : A small light weight PHP class to allow the creation of simple xls excel spreadsheets from array data.
    Version     : 1.01
    Author      : Leenix
    Website     : http://www.leenix.co.uk
*/

/*
    Change Log
        V1 - First Release
        1.01 - Fixed UTF8 Issue
 */

class ExportXLS {

    private $filename;  //Filename which the excel file will be returned as
    private $headerArray;   // Array which contains header information
    private $bodyArray; // Array with the spreadsheet body
    private $rowNo = 0; // Keep track of the row numbers


    #Class constructor
    function ExportXLS($filename) { 
        $this->filename = $filename;
    }


    /*
    -------------------------
    START OF PUBLIC FUNCTIONS
    -------------------------
    */

    public function addHeader($header) {
    #Accepts an array or var which gets added to the top of the spreadsheet as a header.

        if(is_array($header)) {
            $this->headerArray[] = $header;
        }
        else
        {
            $this->headerArray[][0] = $header;
        }
    }

    public function addRow($row) {
    #Accepts an array or var which gets added to the spreadsheet body

        if(is_array($row)) {
            #check for multi dim array
            if(is_array($row[0])) {
                foreach($row as $key=>$array) {
                    $this->bodyArray[] = $array;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                $this->bodyArray[] = $row;
            }           
        }
        else
        {
            $this->bodyArray[][0] = $row;
        }

    }

    public function returnSheet() {
    # returns the spreadsheet as a variable

        #build the xls
        return $this->buildXLS();
    }

    public function sendFile() {

        #build the xls
        $xls = $this->buildXLS();

        #send headers
        header("Pragma: public");
        header("Expires: 0");
        header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
        header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
        header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
        header("Content-Type: application/download");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=".$this->filename);
        header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary ");

        echo $xls;

        exit;
    }


    /*
    --------------------------
    START OF PRIVATE FUNCTIONS
    --------------------------
    */

    private function buildXLS() {
    # build and return the xls 

        #Excel BOF
        $xls = pack("ssssss", 0x809, 0x8, 0x0, 0x10, 0x0, 0x0);

        #build headers
        if(is_array($this->headerArray)) {
            $xls .= $this->build($this->headerArray);
        }

        #build body
        if(is_array($this->bodyArray)) {
            $xls .= $this->build($this->bodyArray);
        }

        $xls .= pack("ss", 0x0A, 0x00);

        return $xls;
    }

    private function build($array) {
    #build and return the headers 

        foreach($array as $key=>$row) {
            $colNo = 0;
            foreach($row as $key2=>$field) {
                if(is_numeric($field)) {
                    $build .= $this->numFormat($this->rowNo, $colNo, $field);
                }
                else
                {
                    $build .= $this->textFormat($this->rowNo, $colNo, $field);
                }

                $colNo++;
            }
            $this->rowNo++;
        }

        return $build;
    }

    private function textFormat($row, $col, $data) {
    # format and return the field as a header
        $data = utf8_decode($data);
        $length = strlen($data);
        $field = pack("ssssss", 0x204, 8 + $length, $row, $col, 0x0, $length);
        $field .= $data;

        return $field; 
    }


    private function numFormat($row, $col, $data) {
    # format and return the field as a header
            $field = pack("sssss", 0x203, 14, $row, $col, 0x0);
            $field .= pack("d", $data); 

        return $field; 
    }
}
?>
```

Demo file :

```
<?php
/*

A quick script to demo the use of the export-xls.class.php script.

*/


#include the export-xls.class.php file
require('export-xls.class.php');


$filename = 'test.xls'; // The file name you want any resulting file to be called.

#create an instance of the class
$xls = new ExportXLS($filename);


#lets set some headers for top of the spreadsheet
#

$header = "Test Spreadsheet"; // single first col text
$xls->addHeader($header);

#add blank line
$header = null;
$xls->addHeader($header);

#add 2nd header as an array of 3 columns
$header[] = "Name";
$header[] = "Age";
$header[] = "Height";

$xls->addHeader($header);


# Lets add some sample data
#
# Of course this can be from a SQL query or anyother data source
#

#first line
$row[] = "Jack";
$row[] = "24";
$row[] = "6ft 5";
$xls->addRow($row);

#second line
$row = array();
$row[] = "Jim";
$row[] = "22";
$row[] = "5ft 5";
$xls->addRow($row);

#add a multi dimension array
$row = array();
$row[] = array(0 =>'Jess', 1=>'54', 2=>'4ft');
$row[] = array(0 =>'Luke', 1=>'6', 2=>'2ft');
$xls->addRow($row);


# You can return the xls as a variable to use with;
# $sheet = $xls->returnSheet();
#
# OR
#
# You can send the sheet directly to the browser as a file 
#
$xls->sendFile();


?>
```

I dont know if works or not but It might help you.

The site I found this was:

https://gist.github.com